# Where to find the source code to the ConTeXt manuals?

Tags: context, examples, resources

Quite a number of helpful manuals can be found at the Web page of [PRAGMA ADE](http://www.pragma-ade.com/document-1.htm). Some have some very interesting designs. I wonder, is there a place to download the source code for some or all of these manuals?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The source code for ConTeXt beginner's manual and the revised reference manual are available at https://foundry.supelec.fr/projects/contextman/.

The source of most other manuals can be browsed at http://context.aanhet.net/svn/. There is a svn repo for other manuals as well, but I cannot find its address.

Comment: Suuplec is a bit unreliable at times. It should be back online in a few hours (or days, sigh)